# Javascript: How to calculate the total number of months?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have wrote a code to split the input into two variables i.e. year and month. But, I am unable to make it work. It does not return the total number of months into the respective text field. Please help me debug my code.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#duration").keyup(function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('duration').value;
    var fields = input.split('.');
    var years = fields[0];
    var months = fields[1];
    var result = years.val() * 12 + months.val();
    document.getElementById("totalNumMonths").innerHTML = result;
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Calculate Months</td>
      <td>
        <label>Input Years in the format (year.month e.g. 11.6)</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="duration" id="duration" value="" type="number" />
        <br/>
        <label>Total Months</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="totalNumMonths" id="totalNumMonths" value="" type="number" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using jQuery but not loading it in your scripts. Open your console. It says `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

Comment: @JeremyThille We do not know it. Maybe he is loading jQuery somewhere else in the file.

Comment: @TN888 We do know it, because I had removed the `<html>` and `<body>` tags from OP's code when I turned it into a snippet. I thought these were useless and irrelevant, but I put the whole original code back, because they show OP is not loading jQuery.

Comment: @JeremyThille Oh, yeah... Now it makes much more sense. Also, OP is mixing jQuery's and JS' syntaxes which is not only unclear but also makes that code prone for error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues with code that I identified and fixed.

- You dont need to access `years.val()` and `months.val()` because `years` and `months` holds string value.
- If your input doesnot have a dot, the value for `months` will be undefined, so you can define `years` and `months` as `fields[0] || "0"` and `fields[1] || "0"` respectiveley.
- Since element with id `totalNumMonths` is an input. You should set the `value` and not `innerHTML`
- Since the `years` and `months` value produces a string, I have added a `+` symbol infront of them while setting the value for `#totalNumMonths` to convert them to number, since we are performing numiric action. Else `+` symbol on string will perform string concatenation.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
$(function () {
  $("#duration").keyup(function () {
    var input = document.getElementById('duration').value;
    var fields = input.split('.');
    var years = fields[0] || "0";
    var months = fields[1]  || "0";
    var result = +years * 12 + +months;
    document.getElementById("totalNumMonths").value = result;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Calculate Months</td>
    <td>
      <label>Input Years in the format (year.month e.g. 11.6)</label>
      <input class="form-control" name="duration" id="duration" value="" type="number" />
      <br />
      <label>Total Months</label>
      <input class="form-control" name="totalNumMonths" id="totalNumMonths" value="" type="number" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is a better answer as it accounts for empty fields. The added + sign must cast strings to integers, which I haven't seen before.

Answer (score 0):

You were calling val on string elements, which caused errors. And the result was adding months as a string value.

```js
$(function () {


    $("#duration").keyup(function () {
    
  
        var input = document.getElementById('duration').value;

        var fields = input.split('.');

        
        var years = parseInt(fields[0]); 
        var months = parseInt(fields[1]);
        
        var result = (years * 12) + months;
        
        document.getElementById("totalNumMonths").value = result;


  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Calculate Months</td>
    <td>
    <label>Input Years in the format (year.month e.g. 11.6)</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="duration" id="duration" value="" type="number"/>
    <br/>
    <label>Total Months</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="totalNumMonths" id="totalNumMonths" value="" type="number"/>
    </td>
   </tr>


  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet, you are having the value of years & months in the respective variables, so you don't need to use `years.val()` to get that value.

Check this out!!

```js
$(function() {
  $("#duration").keyup(function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('duration').value;
    var fields = input.split('.');
    var years = fields[0];
    var months = fields[1] || 0;
    var result = years * 12 + months;
    document.getElementById("totalNumMonths").innerHTML = result;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Calculate Months</td>
    <td>
      <label>Input Years in the format (year.month e.g. 11.6)</label>
      <input class="form-control" name="duration" id="duration" value="" type="number" />
      <br/>
      <label>Total Months :</label>
      <!-- <input class="form-control" name="totalNumMonths" id="totalNumMonths" value="" type="number" /> -->
      <span id="totalNumMonths">0</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```